# groupby multiple coords along a single dimension in xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I have an xarray with multiple coordinates along a single dimension. In the example below, coords `a` and `b` are defined along dimension `dim1`. How would I `groupby` using two coordinates that are defined along the same dimension(s)? Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453426/grouping-by-multiple-dimensions), I am not trying to group along different dimensions, but a single one.

```
import xarray as xr

d = xr.DataArray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]],
    coords={
        'a': ('dim1',['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']),
        'b': ('dim1',['1', '2', '1', '2']),
        'c': ('dim2',['x', 'y', 'z'])
    },
    dims=['dim1', 'dim2'])
d.groupby(['a','b']) # this gives: TypeError: `group` must be an xarray.DataArray or the name of an xarray variable or dimension
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my current workaround:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def groupby_multicoords(da, fields):
    common_dim = da.coords[fields[0]].dims[0]
    tups_arr = np.empty(len(da[common_dim]), dtype=object)
    tups_arr[:] = list(zip(*(da[f].values for f in fields)))
    return da.assign_coords(grouping_zip=xr.DataArray(tups_arr, dims=common_dim)).groupby('grouping_zip')
```

and then, `groupby_multicoords(da=d, fields=['a', 'b'])`

However, after grouping I am still left with the 'grouping_zip' coord. I would be grateful to replace it with `d.groupby(['a','b'])` ..

Comment: what-if: 'a' and 'b' are of different lengths?

Answer (score 1):

You can stack them into a single MultiIndex with `.stack(new=[“dim1”,”dim2”)`, and then groupby that dimension.

Comment: I do not want to groupby dimensions, but rather by coordinates. So I would like to groupby `a` and `b` with groups like: `('A', '1')` or `('B','2')`. These two coordinates are defined along the same dimension in this case.

Comment: Right — appreciate the clarification. You can make `a` & `b` into a stacked dimensioned coordinate, and groupby that. Unfortunately, passing multiple coordinates to `groupby` doesn't currently work.